# Ethereum Miner.start () does not load on the console

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, go-ethereum

Ethereum Miner.start () does not load on the console?

I'm not getting the geth's internal console miner working.

Here's how I'm running the node with open options.

I'm connecting to this node through another geth using the 'geth attach http: 127.0.0.1:8545'

I can connect and use other apis for example: eth, personal. But miner does not work.

Could anyone help?

I am very grateful for the attention.

```
docker run -d --name 'Name' \
    --network ethereum \
    -v $(pwd):/root/.ethereum \
    -v $(pwd):/root/.ethash \
    -v $(pwd)/src:/opt \
    -p 8545:8545 \
    ethereum/client-go:v1.8.12  --bootnodes='...' \
    --networkid=1981 --dev --rpc --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi 'db,eth,net,web3,debug,personal,miner'  --rpccorsdomain '*' --nat=any --cache=512 --verbosity=4 --maxpeers=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the value of `--dev.period` greater than 0, for example `--dev.period 15`

For more information, see the [developer's comment](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15854#issuecomment-357017690).